# Handling multiple actions in one REST call

Tags: rest

We are designing a REST API for a complex data model.  The model is rather like a tree.

```
TOPObject  
  Name: XX  
  Start Date: 01/10/2011  
  End Date: 02/18/2011  
  List  
    NestedObject  
      Name: NO1 
      Code: CCC1  
    NestedObject  
      Name: NO2 
      Code: CCC2
```

Within the client they can work on this whole object on one screen and send all the changes at once.  I don't want to split the resources into two calls: one for TOPObject and one for the NestedObject.  I'd like to make one call to POST for TOPObject.

How do I deal with multiple changes to different levels in the heirarchy.  For example, if they change the object like this.

```
TOPObject  
  Name: XY /* changed */
  Start Date: 01/10/2011  
  End Date: 02/18/2011  
  List  
    NestedObject  
      Name: NO1 
      Code: CCC1  
    /* Notice that NesteObject NO2 was removed as well */
    NestedObject  /* added */
      Name: NO3  
      Code: CCC3
```

So for one call there are three distinct actions: add, update, and delete.  They need to be done as one transaction.

We had an idea to send the "action" with the data, but that doesn't sound RESTful to me.  Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

In effect, all you're doing is modifying your `TOPObject` - removing a NestedObject can be thought of as updating a field. I would expect to be able to send a `PUT` (or `POST`) with my `TopObject` as I want it to be after the modifications and get a `200 OK` back, possibly with a link to `GET` that information back.